# scape pagination content using simple dom parser

Tags: php, dom

I want to scrape title post of a blog and I wrote below code. I stuck in figuring out how to loop through every page.

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://demos.appthemes.com/clipper/');

    scrape('http://demos.appthemes.com/clipper/');

    function scrape($URL)
    {   
        $dom = file_get_html($URL);
        foreach ($dom->find('.item-frame h1 a') as $items) {

            $item = array('courseTitle' => $items->text());

            var_dump($item);
        }
    }

    for($pages = 0; $pages < 3;$pages++) {

            if($next = $dom->find('a[class=page]', $pages)) {
            $URL = $next->href;

            $dom->clear();
            unset($dom);

            scrape($URL);
        }
}
```

Partial result did appear but stuck at an error `Undefined variable: dom in on line 23`

Answer (score 0):

`unset($dom);` causes the `$dom` variable to be unset and on the second loop iteration (`$pages == 1`) call to `$dom->find` fails.

I did not get the logic, but try to remove `$dom->clear(); unset($dom);` lines.

Hope it helps.